# Sending value with path via Ajax Symfony3 & Twig

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, twig

I'm trying to send a value into a path to a Symfony Controller vía Ajax. I am sure that I'm wrong in sending, but I can't find the error

Let me share the code:

### View

I've written

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#my-select").change(function(event){
 var id=$("#my-select").val();  
 var path = "path('go_to_route/" + id+ "')";      
 var route="{{ "+path+" }}";
 alert(path); 
 $.ajax({
  url : route,
  data : {},
  type : 'POST',
  dataType : '',
  success : function(data) {
  alert(data);
  },                
  error : function(xhr, status) {
  alert('Error');
  },
  complete : function(xhr, status) {
  //alert('Finally');
  }
  });
}); 
</script>
```

### Routing

In **routing.yml**

```
go_to_route:
path:     /my-route/{id}
defaults: { _controller: myBundle:MyController:myFunction }
```

This Action is in **MyBundle/MyController**

### Controller

```
public function myFunctionAction($id){
return new Response($id);
}
```

Ajax always return "Error" message. I' think that the error happened while sending the value. I've tried, but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?
This is my first week with Symfony. I'll be grateful for help.

Comment: You could try : var route= '/my-route/' + id on your javascript. Regards

Comment: @Albeis doesn't work

Comment: Have you debugged it? Is the request sent? By going to Network on development console...

Comment: what do you see in your `alert(path);`?

Comment: @simon.ro with my code: path('go_to_route/5')

Comment: For Example.
With my code: alert(path): path('go_to_route/5').
With Albeis attemp alert(route): /my-route/5

Comment: Try return new JsonResponse(array('id' => $id)) on you Response. I Think the ajax should waiting a json response. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
var path = "path('go_to_route/" + id+ "')";      
var route="{{ "+path+" }}";
```

Use:

```
var path = "{{ path('go_to_route', {'id': '__ID__'}) }}";       // Result: var path = "my_route/__ID__";
path = path.replace("__ID__", id);                              // Result: path equals "my_route/17" for example
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
var path = "path('go_to_route/" + id+ "')";
```

Is just a string. Twig doesnt parse that expression, because its not inside {{

You could do

```
var path ='{{ path("go_to_route", {'id': 'xxx'}) }}'; // /my-route/xxx
path = path.replace("xxx", id); // replace xxx with your id
```

You need that replace-value, because twig doesn't know our js-variable `id`.

And theres no need for that `var route="{{ "+path+" }}";`

**All together:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$("#my-select").change(function(event){
 var id=$("#my-select").val();  
 var path ='{{ path("go_to_route", {'id': 'xxx'}) }}';
 path = path.replace("xxx", id);
 $.ajax({
  url : path,
  data : {},
  type : 'POST',
  dataType : '',
  success : function(data) {
  alert(data);
  },                
  error : function(xhr, status) {
  alert('Error');
  },
  complete : function(xhr, status) {
  //alert('Finally');
  }
  });
}); 
</script>
```

**Alternative**

A much cleaner approach would be to use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle

Comment: Works fine! Thanks for explication